# dynamically set the key for Key-Value Coding in objective-c iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary

I have a class called mycallback:

```
[mycallback setValue:[code objectForKey:@"abc"] forKey:@"abc"];
```

It gets called for a lot of my controllers. THe thing is i pull data from a mysql database and I send it to mycallback. So I may not know what the key is. And in addition to that, I don't want to declare instance variables inside mycallback class because I want it separated.

Unfortunately, if the code as is runs above, I get this message:

```
exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CallbackClass 0x7b6c5d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fence.'
```

So I want to dynamically set the keys but not inside mycallback. So I create a category for NSDictionary and add valueForUndefinedKey method:

```
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSLog(@"This key not being called %@", key);
    return nil;
}
```

but 1) valueForUndefinedKey is not called and 2) I'm not sure what to put in there to make that error go away.

thanks for response.

Comment: I rolled the question back to the original state. Your edits made it a completely different question, and my answer below doesn't apply. It makes it confusing for anyone else coming to this question. Rather than radically changing an existing question, please just ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `valueForUndefinedKey:` which is what deals with returning values. But in your code snippet it looks like you are trying to set a value for an undefined key. In which case, the method to use is:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:
```

An example, based on what it looks like you are trying to do:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSLog(@"Attempting to set value: %@ for key: %@", value, key);
}
```

Comment: Im kind of still stuck with the second part of question. I have an instance var named callbackData of type NSMutableDictionary on my callback class which inherits from nsobject. Added the above method to my callback class, and then I set the key and value to the instance var:  [callbackData setObject:value forKey:key]; But error is still raised.